# React Native Navigator: Custom component not visible

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My drawer has nothing displaying in it currently. If I get rid of the custom component it will display the Home option on the drawer. So I know there is something wrong with the way i'm setting up the custom component, but i'm not quite sure what since i'm not getting any errors and I have tried playing around with the style of the component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './component/HomeScreen';
import Settings from './component/Settings';
import {Icon, Button, Container, Header, Content, Left} from 'native-base';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

  return (
    <MyApp/> 
  );
 }
}

const MyApp = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
   screen: HomeScreen
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  drawerPosition: 'right',
  contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
})

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (

  <Container>
    <Header style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: 'white', paddingTop: 50}}>
      <Body>
        <Image style={{width: 30, height: 30}} source={require("./img/close.png")}/>
      </Body>
   </Header>

 </Container>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to import Body from 'native-base' and Image from 'react-native'.

To fix your imports:

`import {Icon, Body, Button, Container, Header, Content, Left} from 'native-base';
 import {Image} from 'react-native';`

Notice I removed the modules StyleSheet, Text and View from `import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';` since they are not being used in your file.